# I am trying to connect to connect to MongoDB from my Express Application. It is throwing a syntax error at my connection string I think

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Hi I am currently working on building and application using Express4 and MongoDB with mongoose. When I try to run my application I am receiving this error

```
    /config/database.js:3
    };
    ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

Database.js is where I am storing the connection string for my DB.

Below is the code contained in database.js

```
    module.exports = {
    mongodb://username:password@ds033669.mongolab.com:33669/dclubdb
    };
```

Here is also my app.js file that is using the database.js the db code is on line 21:

```
    var express = require('express');
    var path = require('path');
    var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
    var logger = require('morgan');
    var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var flash    = require('connect-flash');
    var passport = require('passport');
    var session      = require('express-session');

    var routes = require('./routes/index');
    var users = require('./routes/users');
    var admins = require('./routes/admin');



    var app = express();

    var configDB = require('./config/database.js');


    // view engine setup
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');

    // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
    //app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
    app.use(logger('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(cookieParser());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

    //routes
    app.use('/', routes);
    app.use('/users', users);
    app.use('/admin', users);

    //required for passport
    app.use(session({ secret: 'mysecret' })); // session secret
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
    app.use(flash());


    // catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
    });

    // error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        });
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      });
    });


    //require('./routes/admin.js')(app, passport);


    module.exports = app;
```

Sorry to bother you and thank you for your time in advance. If there any more information I can include please let me know.

Comment: put the value of mongodb connection in quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems with your code as far as I can see:

You seem not to not even connect to mongo. In order to connect to mongo using mongoose you have to use

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://...');
```

Also, your database.js is not valid javascript. It's not the connection string itself that's the problem, but rather that you don't assign in to a variable.

A correct way would be to assign the connection string to a property like this:

```
module.exports = {
    connString: 'mongodb://username:password@ds033669.mongolab.com:33669/dclubdb'
};
```

and then you could connect with

```
mongoose.connect(configDB.connString);
```

Comment: You were correct. It seems the guide I was using was pretty bogus so I am going to go back and just use some of the api's from the different technologies I am needing. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help! Good luck with your application

Answer (score 0):

```
//setup database connection
var options = {
    server: {
        socketOptions: { keepAlive: 1 }
    }
};
mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@server.mongolab.com:port/app', options);
```

To explain (per suggestion).
You typically run MongoDB either locally or through a provider like MongoLab (https://mongolab.com/) (which is free and great for quick development).

Then, to interact with your MongoDB instance, you typically use Mongoose (http://mongoosejs.com/), which is an Object Data Modeler with a lot of useful functionality for doing basic CRUD operations and many other things to your MongoDB instance.

The code sample is using Mongoose ODM to connect to a MongoLab instance.  The connection string is available from the MongoLab interface.

The Options object is documented here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Additionally, although the example uses a hard coded connection string, you probably want to implement a credentials.js file and add it to your .gitignore file so your username and password is not sitting in a code repository.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.